# undefined symbol error when importing libtorch function via pybind11

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11, libtorch

I am attempting to write a C++ function in libtorch, compile it with pybind11 and then import the .so file in a python file.

The build seems to work fine (no errors are emitted) but, when I try to import it into my python file, execution fails with the error message:

**ImportError: /home/cppNpython/MyProj/cpp/build/srcfile.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3c106detail23torchInternalAssertFailEPKcS2_jS2_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE**

demangled version looks as follows:

`undefined symbol: c10::detail::torchInternalAssertFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)`

This is my directory structure:

```sh
|-- MyProj
|   |-- cpp
|   |   |-- build
|   |   |   `-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- include
|   |   |   `-- srcfile.h
|   |   |-- lib
|   |   |   |-- libtorch
|   |   |   `-- pybind11
|   |   |-- source
|   |   |   `-- srcfile.cpp
|   |   `-- CMakeLists.txt
|   `-- __init__.py
`-- test.py
```

Here are the contents of each file:-

**srcfile.cpp**

```cpp
#include <srcfile.h>

torch::Tensor test(torch::Tensor t1, torch::Tensor t2) {
  return t1;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(srcfile, m) {
    m.doc() = "demo function"; // optional module docstring
    m.def("test", &test, "A function giving torch tensor");
}
```

**srcfile.h**

```cpp
#ifndef __SRCFILE_H__
#define __SRCFILE_H__

#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

torch::Tensor test(torch::Tensor, torch::Tensor);

#endif
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```sh
project(srcfile)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "lib/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

include_directories(lib/libtorch)

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(lib/pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(srcfile src/srcfile.cpp)

target_include_directories(srcfile PRIVATE include/)
target_link_libraries(srcfile PUBLIC ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})

set_property(TARGET srcfile PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

and at last **test.py**

```py
import torch
from MyProj.cpp.build import srcfile as j

def main():
    t1 = torch.rand(2,2)
    t2 = torch.rand(2,2)
    print(j.test(t1, t2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Inside the `build` directory I am executing the following command at the terminal:

```sh
cmake .. \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())")  \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))") \
-DTORCH_LIBRARIES=lib/libtorch && make
```

which does not emit any error.
I get the error only when I am attempting to import.

### I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help/suggestion is welcome.

output of `ldd srcfile.so`

```sh
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc893da000)
libtorch_cpu.so => /home/cppNpython/MyProj/cpp/lib/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so (0x00007f0183880000)
libtorch.so => /home/cppNpython/MyProj/cpp/lib/libtorch/lib/libtorch.so (0x00007f0199db7000)
libc10.so => /home/cppNpython/MyProj/cpp/lib/libtorch/lib/libc10.so (0x00007f0199d3a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f01834f7000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f01832df000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0182eee000)
libgomp-52f2fd74.so.1 => /home/cppNpython/MyProj/cpp/lib/libtorch/lib/libgomp-52f2fd74.so.1 (0x00007f0182cbb000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0182a9c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0182894000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0182690000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f01822f2000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0199c2d000)
```

Comment: No needs to comment with the error message (and its demangling variant): just add this information directly into the question post.

Comment: It seems that you're linking to libtorch dynamically, but that you don't find it while loading the library in Python. Can you run `ldd srcfile.so` to see if there's a missing library?

Comment: @anurag I just stumbled upon a very similarly looking bug. Did you manage to solve what the cause was in your case?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an ABI issue - you can see the missing symbol contains `std::__cxx11::basic_string` which means your library is built with the ["new" `std::string` ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_dual_abi.html). To my understanding torch is usually built with `D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and the old ABI.

You can add `add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)` to your cmake file or configure your torch compilation to use the new ABI.

Comment: simply adding the `add_definition()` call in cmake did not help. Could you please tell me which libtorch version I should be using? `libtorch 10.2 CXX11 ABI` or `libtorch 10.2 pre CXX11 ABI`

Comment: `libtorch 10.2 CXX11 ABI` I think.