# Undefined symbols when importing a C++ extension

Tags: pytorch, libtorch

(I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71164189/688080) but I have tried both ABIs with the corresponding `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` values and neither works; nor with the PyTorch built from source with `torch._C._GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI = True`)

My project structure:

```
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- main.cpp
|-- main.py
|-- pybind11
|-- libtorch
```

and the files

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(TORCH_LINK_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options(-O3 -fPIC)

set(PYBIND11_FINDPYTHON ON)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pybind11)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED HINTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libtorch)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(target link_error)
pybind11_add_module(${target} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(${target} PRIVATE ${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${target} PRIVATE ${pybind11_LIBRARIES} ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})

add_custom_command(TARGET ${target} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink $<TARGET_FILE:${target}> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${target}.so
)
```

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <array>
#include <memory>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <torch/extension.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct IdentityImpl : public torch::nn::Module
{
  torch::Tensor forward(const torch::Tensor &x) { return x; }
};

TORCH_MODULE(Identity);

class RandomTensor
{
  public:
  RandomTensor(const std::array<int64_t, 4> &shape)
      : shape_(shape), options_(torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat32).device(torch::kCUDA).requires_grad(false))
  {
  }
  torch::Tensor draw() { return m_->forward(torch::randn(shape_, options_)); }

  private:
  std::array<int64_t, 4> shape_;
  torch::TensorOptions options_;
  Identity m_;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(link_error, m)
{
  py::class_<RandomTensor>(m, "RandomTensor")
      .def("draw", &RandomTensor::draw, py::call_guard<py::gil_scoped_release>())
      .def(py::init<const std::array<int64_t, 4>&>());
}
```

```py
# main.py

import torch
from link_error import RandomTensor

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rt = RandomTensor([1, 2, 2, 2])
    print(rt.draw())
```

After a successful build, the error below happens when importing:

```sh
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from link_error import RandomTensor
ImportError: link_error.so: undefined symbol: _Z16THPVariable_WrapN2at10TensorBaseE
```

For what may help, here is the output from `ldd`:

```sh
$ ldd link_error.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe5dfd9000)
    libtorch_cuda.so => libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so (0x00007f01dc76b000)
    libtorch_cuda_cpp.so => libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so (0x00007f017352d000)
    libtorch_cpu.so => libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so (0x00007f015b4eb000)
    libtorch_cuda_cu.so => libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cu.so (0x00007f0122a00000)
    libtorch.so => libtorch/lib/libtorch.so (0x00007f01227fe000)
    libnvToolsExt.so.1 => /usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64/libnvToolsExt.so.1 (0x00007f01225f3000)
    libcudart.so.11.0 => /usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64/libcudart.so.11.0 (0x00007f012235a000)
    libc10.so => libtorch/lib/libc10.so (0x00007f01220db000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0121e99000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0121e7e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0121c8c000)
    libc10_cuda.so => libtorch/lib/libc10_cuda.so (0x00007f012199c000)
    libcudart-a7b20f20.so.11.0 => libtorch/lib/libcudart-a7b20f20.so.11.0 (0x00007f01216ff000)
    libnvToolsExt-24de1d56.so.1 => libtorch/lib/libnvToolsExt-24de1d56.so.1 (0x00007f01214f5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f01214d2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f01214cc000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f01214c2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0121371000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f01dc995000)
    libgomp-52f2fd74.so.1 => libtorch/lib/libgomp-52f2fd74.so.1 (0x00007f012113e000)
```

`THPVariable_Wrap` appears in `libtorch_python.so` according to `nm`, but explicitly adding the library to `target_link_libraries` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the JIT compilation. See https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html#jit-compiling-extensions

Example:

```
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import load

lltm = load(name='lltm', sources=['lltm_cuda.cpp', 'lltm_cuda_kernel.cu'])
```

Comment: I saw someone mentioned this in GitHub issue too. Why does it work?